# How to get the info in table header (schema)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

env: spark2.4.5

source: id-name.json

```
{"1": "a", "2": "b", "3":, "c"..., "n": "z"}
```

I load the .json file into spark Dataset with Json format and it is stored like:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 |...| n |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| a | b | c |...| z |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

And I want it to be generated like such result:

```
+------------+------+
|     id     | name |
+------------+------+
| 1          | a    |
| 2          | b    |
| 3          | c    |
| .          | .    |
| .          | .    |
| .          | .    |
| n          | z    |
+------------+------+
```

My solution using spark-sql:

```
select stack(n, '1', `1`, '2', `2`... ,'n', `n`) as ('id', 'name') from table_name;
```

It doesn't meet my demand because I don't want to hard-code all the 'id' in sql. 
Maybe using '*show columns from table_name*' with '*stack()*' can help? 
I would be very grateful if you could give me some suggestion.

Comment: One question, will have the table  only two columns?

Comment: yep, multi to 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create required values for `stack` dynamic & use it where ever it required. Please check below code to generate same values dynamic.

```
scala> val js = Seq("""{"1": "a", "2": "b","3":"c","4":"d","5":"e"}""").toDS
js: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String] = [value: string]

scala> val df = spark.read.json(js)
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [1: string, 2: string ... 3 more fields]

scala> val stack = s"""stack(${df.columns.max},${df.columns.flatMap(c => Seq(s"'${c}'",s"`${c}`")).mkString(",")}) as (id,name)"""
exprC: String = stack(5,'1',`1`,'2',`2`,'3',`3`,'4',`4`,'5',`5`) as (id,name)

scala> df.select(expr(stack)).show(false)
+---+----+
|id |name|
+---+----+
|1  |a   |
|2  |b   |
|3  |c   |
|4  |d   |
|5  |e   |
+---+----+


scala> spark.sql(s"""select ${stack} from table """).show(false)
+---+----+
|id |name|
+---+----+
|1  |a   |
|2  |b   |
|3  |c   |
|4  |d   |
|5  |e   |
+---+----+


scala>
```

`Updated Code to fetch data from json file`

```
scala> "hdfs dfs -cat /tmp/sample.json".!
{"1": "a", "2": "b","3":"c","4":"d","5":"e"}
res4: Int = 0

scala> val df = spark.read.json("/tmp/sample.json")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [1: string, 2: string ... 3 more fields]

scala> val stack = s"""stack(${df.columns.max},${df.columns.flatMap(c => Seq(s"'${c}'",s"`${c}`")).mkString(",")}) as (id,name)"""
stack: String = stack(5,'1',`1`,'2',`2`,'3',`3`,'4',`4`,'5',`5`) as (id,name)

scala> df.select(expr(stack)).show(false)
+---+----+
|id |name|
+---+----+
|1  |a   |
|2  |b   |
|3  |c   |
|4  |d   |
|5  |e   |
+---+----+

scala> df.createTempView("table")

scala> spark.sql(s"""select ${stack} from table """).show(false)
+---+----+
|id |name|
+---+----+
|1  |a   |
|2  |b   |
|3  |c   |
|4  |d   |
|5  |e   |
+---+----+
```

Comment: Are you suggesting to load the JSON file as Sequence ?

Comment: I am telling build your stack like this - val stack = s"""stack(${df.columns.max},${df.columns.flatMap(c => Seq(s"'${c}'",s"`${c}`")).mkString(",")}) as (id,name)""" .. its completly dynamic.

Comment: have you tried your solution with loading JSON file data instead of a Seq ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried & updated my solution with same code.

Comment: @QuickSilver, are you facing any issue ? I have not taken complete json which mentioned in question. took some portion of json & executed code.

Comment: @Srinivas, thanks a lot! It works for me although I use Java API. Another question: Can it be achieved by just spark-sql (without any API)?

Comment: Thanks , i will check that & will update answer if i get any solution.